Reordering the months on the x-axis of bar chart in R
I am having trouble reordering the months on the x-axis so that they display in the correct order (ie. January, February, March, etc.). Right now the order I am getting is alphabetical; April, August, December, February, January... Any help would be appreciated! Here's my code below.

df %\>%
    mutate(month = months(started_at)) %\>%
    group_by(member_casual, month) %\>%
    summarise(number_of_rides = n()) %\>%
    arrange(member_casual, month)  %\>%
    ggplot(aes(x = month, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5,hjust=1))



output

There is no data to work with.

There's a helpful search function to find prior answers to this question, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555115/reordering-month-results-in-the-x-axis-ggplot and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137624/need-help-reordering-month and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873651/reordering-months-in-ggplot2-x-axis and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020146/how-can-i-order-the-months-chronologically-in-ggplot2-short-of-writing-the-month.  Try [r] month order or similar and you should see lots of responsive answers.

Perhaps this was a pasting issue or something, but presumably you mean %>% instead of %\>%

The two typical approaches are to either make your month into an ordered factor, or make it into a Date object (e.g. if started_at is something like February, we could say mutate(month_date = lubridate::make_date(2024, started_at, 1)) to make it into a Date 2024-02-01, which ggplot2 will plot chronologically. You could then use scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month", date_labels = "%B", minor_breaks = NULL) to get monthly breaks.
